# BOOTCAMP | No choice to locate ISO

Tags: bootcamp, windows, utilities

This is my first time ever trying to use Boot Camp Assistant.  I've watched like 50 tutorials and every had a choice to pick/locate an ISO image. I don't (see 2nd image). Is there a solution to this?

[image]

[image: **enter image description here**]

Comment: That option only appears on Macs without optical drives. If you have a Windows DVD, your Mac will ask you to insert it in order to start the Boot Camp partitioning process.

Answer (score 1):

If you have already made your boot stick try moving the .iso out of any folders into the main part of the drive. sometimes it can't find it. Also make sure you have a legitimate .iso that can also cause problems to if parts of the file are missing etc.